# GStreamer splitting into multiple M4S files

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to hook up splitmuxsink to create multiple .m4s files.  I can get that to work if I skip the audio.  When I try to include the audio, it fails to link the elements.  The error is specifically at:

`gst_element_link_many(pData->audioSource,aac_parse,sink,NULL)`

Additionally, if I can hook the exact same audio elements to mp4mux and it successfully produces a MP4 file with audio and video.

If it matters, I'm emitting "push-buffer" to send AAC and H.264 data to "appsrc".

```
void* gst_pipeline_setup(void)
{
   CustomData* pData = malloc(sizeof(CustomData));
   memset(pData, 0, sizeof(*pData));
   pData->sentSps = FALSE;
   
   GstStateChangeReturn ret;

   /* Initialize GStreamer */
   gst_init(NULL, NULL);

   /* Create the elements */
   pData->audioSource = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "audio-source");
   pData->videoSource = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "video-source");

   GstElement* aac_parse = gst_element_factory_make("aacparse", "aac-parse");
   GstElement* video_parser = gst_element_factory_make("h264parse", "video-parser");

   GstElement* sink = gst_element_factory_make("splitmuxsink", "sink");

   /* Create the empty pipeline */
   pData->pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("test-pipeline");

   if (!pData->pipeline || 
      !pData->audioSource ||
      !aac_parse ||
      !sink ||
      !pData->videoSource ||
      !video_parser
   ) {
      g_printerr("Not all elements could be created.\n");
      free(pData);
      return NULL;
   }

   // Configure appsrc
   GstCaps* caps = gst_caps_new_simple("audio/mpeg", 
      "mpegversion", G_TYPE_INT, 4, 
      "profile", G_TYPE_INT, 2,  // Profile 2 corresponds to AAC-LC
      NULL);

   g_object_set(G_OBJECT(pData->audioSource), "caps", caps, NULL);
   gst_caps_unref(caps);

   gchar* to = "output_segment-%05d.m4s"; // Replace with your desired output pattern
   guint64 duration = 4000000000; // 4 seconds in nanoseconds, adjust as needed

   g_object_set(sink, "location", to, NULL);
   g_object_set(sink, "max-size-time", duration, NULL);
   g_object_set(sink, "muxer-factory", "mp4mux", NULL);

   // Configure appsrc
   GstCaps* videoCaps = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-h264",
      "stream-format", G_TYPE_STRING, "byte-stream",
      "alignment", G_TYPE_STRING, "nal",
      "width", G_TYPE_INT, 1920 *2,
      "height", G_TYPE_INT, 1080 *2,
      "pixel-aspect-ratio", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 1, 1,
      "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1,
      NULL);

   g_object_set(G_OBJECT(pData->videoSource), "caps", videoCaps, NULL);
   gst_caps_unref(videoCaps);

   /* Build the pipeline. Note that we are NOT linking the source at this
    * point. We will do it later. */
   gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pData->pipeline), 
      pData->audioSource,
      aac_parse,
      pData->videoSource,
      video_parser,
      //muxer,
      sink,
      NULL);


   if (!gst_element_link_many(pData->audioSource,
      aac_parse,
      sink,
      NULL)) {
      g_printerr("Audio elements could not be linked.\n");
      gst_object_unref(pData->pipeline);
      free(pData);
      return NULL;
   }

   if (!gst_element_link_many(pData->videoSource,
      video_parser,
      sink,
      NULL)) {
      g_printerr("Video elements could not be linked.\n");
      gst_object_unref(pData->pipeline);
      free(pData);
      return NULL;
   }

   /* Start playing */
   ret = gst_element_set_state(pData->pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
   if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
      g_printerr("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
      gst_object_unref(pData->pipeline);
      free(pData);
      return NULL;
   }

   return pData;
}
```

I turned on some extra debug, and maybe it's trying to hook the audio from aacparse to the video of splitmuxsink?

````
0:00:05.427745000 13392 000001EDF1C09F90 DEBUG           splitmuxsink gstsplitmuxsink.c:3415:gst_splitmux_sink_request_new_pad:<sink> searching for pad-template with name 'video_%u'
0:00:05.428216700 13392 000001EDF1C09F90 DEBUG           splitmuxsink gstsplitmuxsink.c:3469:gst_splitmux_sink_request_new_pad:<sink> found sink pad-template 'video_%u' on the muxer
0:00:05.428527200 13392 000001EDF1C09F90 DEBUG           splitmuxsink gstsplitmuxsink.c:3472:gst_splitmux_sink_request_new_pad:<sink> requesting pad from pad-template
0:00:05.432235300 13392 000001EDF1C09F90 DEBUG           splitmuxsink gstsplitmuxsink.c:3566:gst_splitmux_sink_request_new_pad:<sink> splitmuxsink pad <'':video> feeds queue pad <queue_video:sink>
0:00:05.432761000 13392 000001EDF1C09F90 INFO            splitmuxsink gstsplitmuxsink.c:3608:gst_splitmux_sink_release_pad:<sink:video> releasing request pad```
````

Comment: I was able to "fix" it by adding `gst_element_request_pad_simple(sink, "audio_%u")` before linking the audio, but this feels incorrect.